# Nodejs Swagger 2.0 No operations defined in spec! on dist

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

I defined the swagger option below:

```
const swaggerDocOptions = {   explorer: true,   definition: {
    swagger: '2.0',
    components: {},
    info: {
      title: 'Document API',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'document API',
    },
    schemes: [
      'http',
      'https',
    ],
    security: [{
      simple: [],
    }],
    securityDefinitions: {
      simple: {
        type: 'basic',
      },
    },   },   basedir: `${__dirname}`,   apis: [
    `${__dirname}\\routes\\*.js`,   ], };

const specs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerDocOptions);
 app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(specs));
```

The Api doc can display successfully when I run on my local
[image]

And then I try to deploy to server with bytenote
and the __dirname = app/dist on server, but the Api doc does not display
[image]

Could you advise, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Then I realized when I built the node application, its routes(API endpoints) location got changed. That is why it was working in locally but not in the build version.

I have changed apis attribute value from `apis:["./src/modules/**/*.ts"]` to `apis:["./dist/modules/**/*.js"]`

In my case, `dist` is the build folder name.